# Spinner dialog click outside text

Tags: android

I'm using a custom Spinner in a dialog mode. Each item element has one text. The text in each item line is very short, eg. "A", "AB", "BC", etc. In order to select a line I have to click exactly the text (the background is than changing into blue and the item is selected correctly). When I click outside this short text but in the item line it is not selected. Is it possible to force the selection when I click the item line not exactly the item text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a custom spinner then you should be able to access the textview element in the xml for the class.

In this xml,  the textview element try changing the property

```
Android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

You may also use the padding and margin to adjust the same.